# Would rather they WENT by bus than WALK

Tags: subjunctive-mood, sequence-of-tenses, would, bare-infinitive

> 1. I would rather you **washed** it yourself than **see** your mom do it for you.

> 2. I would rather you **washed** the dishes than **watched** TV.

> 3. The mom would rather the kids **went** by bus than **walk**.

I can understand, perhaps, why we have the modal past tense *washed* in the first clause in (1) and an infinitive in the second. I think this is because the first clause is short for *rather **see** you washed it by hand*.

The second example is of course straightforward because it has a past tense in each clause.

I don't understand the grammar of (3), however. Why does (and why can) it use a modal past tense *went* in the first clause but an infinitive in the second?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138662/discussion-on-question-by-svetlana-would-rather-they-went-by-bus-than-walk).

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive does not carry a sense of tense. Your examples can be better rendered as

*I would rather he **wash** it himself than see your mom do it for you.*

*I would rather he **wash** the dishes than watch TV.*

*The mom would rather the kid **go** by bus than walk.*

so as to coincide with the verb in the second clause.

(You will note that I have changed the subjects to the 3rd person singular to demonstrate the subjunctive more clearly.)

Comment: Good thinking, Batman! But if you hadn't explicitly mentioned switching to *3rd person **singular***, I might have missed it!

Answer (score 0):

- What linguistic explanation stands beyond: “The mom would rather the kids went by bus than walk”? (for me “went” is not homogeneous with “walk” in this case as the forms are different)

"Homogeneity" is not quite the concept involved, and it is better to speak of parallel structures. ([The Evergreen Writing Center](https://www.evergreen.edu/sites/default/files/writingcenter/handouts/grammar/parallel.pdf))

Parallelism is a necessity (stylistic) as pertains to coordination, but this is not a case of coordination, at least not pure coordination. Taking a similar construction in which "rather than" is considered to be a quasi-coordinator, the same lack of parallelism is accepted as normal.

> **CoGEL, QUASI-COORDINATORS**
> **13.103**
> […] there are several linking items which we may call QUASI-COORDINATORS,
> because they behave sometimes like coordinators, and at other times like
> subordinators or prepositions. The most prominent of them are clearly
> related to comparative forms:
>       *as well as, as much as, **rather than**, more than*
>
> • I'm going to forget the whole affair, rather than cause trouble.
>
> • I would forget the whole affair, rather than cause trouble. (*modified by user LPH*)

•  I would rather forget the whole affair than cause trouble. (*slightly  different meaning*)

Moreover, the infinitive mood is used in so-called NONFINITE forms, of which the bare infinitive is one.  We may easily see that in those instances of use of the nonfinite forms, the action named  *is not performed*.

- He wanted *to be* at his sister's.
- He may *be*  at his sister's.
- Why *be* so sad?

This is just what the subjunctive is used for, actions that are merely being considered, and so, from that point of view, the infinitive is a logical replacement.

---

Reply to this [comment by user Svetlana](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593848/what-linguistic-explanation-stands-beyond-subject-1would-ratherbare-infinitiv#comment1492603_593858)

It doesn't matter whether in the context there are kids actually walking to school or not. What is being considered  is *the action in general*, not the kid's action as they walk to school everyday. Whether they walk, or take the bus, or some neighbour's wife is driving them, you can say this, that is, this is a meaningful sentence: "The parents are thinking about transportation, and their mom would rather the kids went by bus than walk.".
In this particular  case  when they do  go by bus you still use the subjunctive "went" to speak about  the action, which is merely being considered. This  is confirmed in PEU (*PracticalEnglishUsage*).

> ***would rather*: past  tense with  present or future meaning**
>
> We can use *would rather* to say that one person would prefer another or others to do something. We use a special  structure with a past tense.
>
> *would rather* + subject + past tense
>
> • *I'**d rather you went** homenow*.
> • *Tomorrow's difficult. I'**d rather you  came**next weekend*
>
> A  present tense is  sometimes used in this structure (e.g. *I'd rather you **go**  home now*),  but it is unusual.

Comment: LPH, I am much greatful for parallel constructions - super info!  Still, the Infinitive "walk" is  not for the action which is not performed in this case. I think, the kids walked in reality. The unreal is expressed by the verb-form "went". OR: " walk" is attached to "the mom"? OR: it is a matter of "speech habits"  - usus? In any case, thanks a lot for the attention to the point and your explanation! I am considering it and reading further!

Comment: @Svetlana Both *I’d rather he call than write* and *I’d rather he called than wrote* are possible, but so is *I’d rather him call than write* meaning *I would prefer for him to call rather than for him to write*.  However, the nonparallel *I’d rather he called than write* is not unknown simply because English speakers don't always pay careful attention to their tense structures in casual utterances, perhaps because the meaning does not change when the inflections mismatch like this.

Comment: If you don't quite understand how comparative constructions are formed, be aware that nobody does. They are immensely complex, involving at least two quantifiers and a negative, producing scope ambiguities galore, and lending themselves to obscure constructions like these.

Comment: Both I’d rather he call than write and I’d rather he called than wrote are possible, but so is I’d rather him call than write meaning I would prefer for him to call rather than for him to write.  - Thanks a lot for the explanation! I use these constructions as they are clear to me. The problem was with the test online where correct answers were like the one above.  I am grateful for your comment!

Comment: @Svetlana  I wrote my reply in my post.

Comment: Would the downvoter take the pain to leave a couple of words of explanation?